# ADO SQL query create column if it doesn't exist

Tags: sql, ms-access, ado

I have a query for a report based on an MS Access database (as the program project file).  The tables in this database get updated with new fields periodically as new features are added.

We need to be able to support old and new versions of the file for our report, so need to know if there is a way to insert a field into the SQL SELECT query if it does not already exist. (Note: Do not want to create ALTER TABLE type statements, as the field only needs to be added into the result set, not into the table permanently.)

I know you can do something like ***"" AS [FieldName]***, but that only applies when you know the field doesn't exist and need to create a blank spot for it (such as when a unioned table does have that field).  In this case, the table might have the field so I want to use it if it does, but if it doesn't I want to have it still exist in the query results with a default value.

Any help would be appreciated.  (I also know you can force the user to update the file, but that option was stated as "only last resort".)

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: In a select statement there is no way to dynamically select a column based on if it exists in the schema or not. If that is not what you are talking about please add code to the question to clarify it.

Comment: Requires VBA code and QueryDefs to modify query object.

Comment: Than you very much for the update.  I figured there was not really a way to do it in the query directly, but figured I would ask the question just in case.  I will have to go the route of forcing the user to update the project file then.